# Split String by | and numbers

Tags: java, regex, split

Let's imagine I have the following strings:

```
String one = "123|abc|123abc";
String two = "123|ab12c|abc|456|abc|def";
String three = "123|1abc|1abc1|456|abc|wer";
String four = "123|abc|def|456|ghi|jkl|789|mno|pqr";
```

If I do a split on them I expect the following output:

```
one = ["123|abc|123abc"];
two = ["123|ab12c|abc", "456|abc|def"];
three = ["123|1abc|1abc1", "456|abc|wer"];
four = ["123|abc|def", "456|ghi|jkl", "789|mno|pqr"];
```

The string has the following structure:

Starts with 1 or more digits followed by a random number of (| followed by random number of characters).

When after a | it's only numbers is considered a new value.

More examples:

```
In - 123456|xxxxxx|zzzzzzz|xa2314|xzxczxc|1234|qwerty
Out - ["123456|xxxxxx|zzzzzzz|xa2314|xzxczxc", "1234|qwerty"]
```

Tried multiple variations of the following but does not work:

```
value.split( "\\|\\d+|\\d+" )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may split on `\|(?=\d+(?:\||$))`:

```java
List<String> nums = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
    "123|abc|123abc",
    "123|ab12c|abc|456|abc|def",
    "123|1abc|1abc1|456|abc|wer",
    "123|abc|def|456|ghi|jkl|789|mno|pqr"
});

for (String num : nums) {
    String[] parts = num.split("\\|(?=\\d+(?:\\||$))");
    System.out.println(num + " => " + Arrays.toString(parts));
}
```

This prints:

```
123|abc|123abc => [123|abc|123abc]
123|ab12c|abc|456|abc|def => [123|ab12c|abc, 456|abc|def]
123|1abc|1abc1|456|abc|wer => [123|1abc|1abc1, 456|abc|wer]
123|abc|def|456|ghi|jkl|789|mno|pqr => [123|abc|def, 456|ghi|jkl, 789|mno|pqr]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting, you can match the parts in the string:

```
\b\d+(?:\|(?!\d+(?:$|\|))[^|\r\n]+)*
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\|(?!\d+(?:$|\|))` Match `|` and assert not only digits till either the next pipe or the end of the string
  - `[^|\r\n]+` Match 1+ chars other than a pipe or a newline
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat (use `+` to repeat one or more times to match at least one pipe char)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/joPbuD/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/jLSzQ4)

```
String regex = "\\b\\d+(?:\\|(?!\\d+(?:$|\\|))[^|\\r\\n]+)+";
String string = "123|abc|def|456|ghi|jkl|789|mno|pqr";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();

while (m.find()) 
    matches.add(m.group());

for (String s : matches)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output

```
123|abc|def
456|ghi|jkl
789|mno|pqr
```